# How to setup a shared list of contacts in Office 365?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365, contacts

In Office 365, I would like to set a list of contacts as *shared* across a list of users (who all belong to the same organization via the Azure AD running Office 365). All users should have the possibility to CRUD (create/read/update/delete) the contacts. The solution should not involve manually re-sharing every contact every single time an edition is made. How do I achieve this? Via a *shared mailbox*?

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.

Answer (score 1):

See the article
[Office Q&A: How to share Outlook 365 contacts](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/office-q-a-how-to-share-outlook-365-contacts/).

Sharing a contacts folder is done
in the People window, Home tab, click Share Contacts in the Share group.

However, it is doubtful that others will be able to update your list,
unless you are all within the same organization.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, members of a shared mailbox will be able to access the shared calendar and contacts. So, to achieve your requirement, it's suggested that you could create a shared mailbox and assign permissions to the members. For more specific steps, please refer to: [Sharing calendar and contacts in Microsoft 365](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/troubleshoot/calendaring/how-to-share-calendar-and-contacts#which-microsoft-365-plan-do-you-use).

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.